# How to get first one from Sequence Index python

Tags: python

I have following sequence index:

```
[{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7THE', u'confidence': 92.405113},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TBE', u'confidence': 83.526604},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TRE', u'confidence': 82.455276},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7T8E', u'confidence': 82.432587},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7THE', u'confidence': 80.914902},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7THE', u'confidence': 80.913948},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7THB', u'confidence': 78.234192},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'GA7THE', u'confidence': 78.146278},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TE', u'confidence': 77.999985},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'A7THE', u'confidence': 77.449036},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TH6', u'confidence': 76.716492},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7TBE', u'confidence': 72.036392},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7TBE', u'confidence': 72.035439},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7TRE', u'confidence': 70.965065},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7TRE', u'confidence': 70.964104},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7T8E', u'confidence': 70.942375},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7T8E', u'confidence': 70.941422},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TBB', u'confidence': 69.355682},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'GA7TBE', u'confidence': 69.267769},
{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'A7TBE', u'confidence': 68.570526}]
```

I tried for loop to get only plate values from this sequence index.

```
EA7THE
EA7TBE
EA7TRE
EA7T8E
6A7THE
BA7THE
EA7THB
GA7THE
EA7TE
A7THE
EA7TH6
6A7TBE
BA7TBE
6A7TRE
BA7TRE
6A7T8E
BA7T8E
EA7TBB
GA7TBE
A7TBE
A7TBE
```

This is code for it. But I don't know how to get first of these sequence index. Please help to get first plate value of it.

```
for candidate in plate['candidates']:  
        print(candidate['plate'])
```

I would like to know how to get plate number of maximum confidence value. I know this is stupid question. Sorry for that.

Comment: So you want `len(list)` ?

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension I think:

```
[c.get('plate') for c in plate_list ][0]
```

==>u'EA7THE'

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort `list of dictionaries by values'. So if sorted in ascending order, you retrieve the last one and if sorted by descending values, retrieve the first one.

```
a = [{u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7THE', u'confidence': 92.405113}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TBE', u'confidence': 83.526604}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TRE', u'confidence': 82.455276}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7T8E', u'confidence': 82.432587}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7THE', u'confidence': 80.914902}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7THE', u'confidence': 80.913948}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7THB', u'confidence': 78.234192}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'GA7THE', u'confidence': 78.146278}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TE', u'confidence': 77.999985}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'A7THE', u'confidence': 77.449036}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TH6', u'confidence': 76.716492}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7TBE', u'confidence': 72.036392}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7TBE', u'confidence': 72.035439}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7TRE', u'confidence': 70.965065}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7TRE', u'confidence': 70.964104}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'6A7T8E', u'confidence': 70.942375}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'BA7T8E', u'confidence': 70.941422}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'EA7TBB', u'confidence': 69.355682}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'GA7TBE', u'confidence': 69.267769}, {u'matches_template': 0, u'plate': u'A7TBE', u'confidence': 68.570526}]

a = sorted(a, key= lambda k:k['confidence'])

print a [-1]['plate']
```

> Output: EA7THE

[Demo](http://ideone.com/oXscsn)